# C Shell でサーバ間のファイル転送は可能？

Tags: linux, shell, csh

クーロンで.cshを起動・実行し、サーバAからサーバBにファイルを転送したいと考えていますが、可能ですか？

不可能な場合、Linuxでサーバ間のファイル転送を日次で実行する方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/216129

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cシェルそのものにサーバ間でのファイル転送機能はないので、やりたいことを実現するには
`rsync` や `scp` コマンドが良いのかなと思います。

**参考:**

- [rsync コマンド - ファイルやディレクトリを同期する](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1702/02/news031.html)
- [scp コマンド - リモートマシンとの間でファイルをコピーする](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1701/27/news009.html)

これらを `cron` のジョブとして登録すれば日次実行が可能です。

Answer (score 1):

シェルを問わず、Linux コマンドが使えるのであれば [scp コマンド](https://tech.nikkeibp.co.jp/it/article/COLUMN/20070723/277942/)や [rsync コマンド](https://tech.nikkeibp.co.jp/it/article/COLUMN/20070822/280169/)が使えます。

```sh
scp 〈送るファイルのパス〉 serverB:〈送る先のパス〉
rsync -chavzP 〈送るファイルのパス〉 serverB:〈送る先のパス〉
```

Answer (score 0):

cronでcshスクリプトを起動・実行し、サーバAからサーバBにファイルを転送することは可能です。

質問された方の環境が不明なので、杞憂かもしれませんが、
cshスクリプトのシェバン(スクリプトの先頭に記述するコメント)が
`#`だけの場合、cronがcshスクリプトを実行するときにエラーとなる場合があります。
cronのデーモンがコマンドを実行するとき、スクリプトがcshで書かれているかを判断できません。シェバンをみて起動するシェルを決めます。

古い環境では、`#`だけの行があると、そのスプリプトは`csh`で書かれていると判断されますが、最近の環境では`#!/bin/csh`(※)と書いておかないと`csh`のスクリプトだと判断してもらえない可能性が高いです。※cshが/binに配置されているかは環境によります。

古い環境で作成されたcshスクリプトをベースに新しいスクリプトを書いたとき、cshの環境で動いていても、cronに登録すると動かないことはよくあります。

Answer (score 0):

今どきピュア `ftp` は他の方法でセキュリティが担保されている場合に限定して使うべきで、普通は `rsync` なり `scp` なり 使うべきというのは皆様の書いている通りっす。

さらに追加するとシェルスクリプトを記述する場合は `bourne-shell` つまり `sh` あるいは `dash` で書くべきです。最近の Linux に限定するなら `bash` の拡張文法を使ってもかまわないでしょうが `csh` で書くのはダメダメです。 [有害な csh プログラミング](http://www.speech-lab.org/~hiroki/csh-whynot.euc) とか [Wikipedia の cshell](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Shell) の批判の節とか参照。

Comment: 「csh で書くのはダメダメです。」新規に作成するときは私もそう思いますが、世の中にはいまだに`csh`で書かれたスクリプトをメンテナンスすることも多いのでこの表現は少し気になりました。

Comment: 今回のこの件については新規にスクリプト書くのでしょうから csh で書くな sh で書け、と言いたかったわけです。既にある csh スクリプトをメンテすることがありうる件については御意。でもオイラが csh スクリプト直す羽目になったら１行１か所の修正で済むような場合を除き sh に書き直しちゃってます。